# Is there any climate science explanation for this graph besides severe anthropogenic heating?

Tags: climate-change

Since 1950 surface temperatures have risen significantly even though the total radiant energy from the Sun has been decreasing over this same period. To the best of my current understanding as long as these two graphs are accurate this makes it game over for the climate change deniers.

**Is there any climate science explanation for the significant increase in surface temperatures corresponding to a decrease in radiant energy besides severe anthropogenic heating?**

https://climate.nasa.gov/faq/14/is-the-sun-causing-global-warming/?fbclid=IwAR2d6RW0KpLXRifAU4hZPbEjXVLnRcLRshw233gGJW--47tl0NfdY7JMTyk

[image]

Comment: As others have noted, you're asking effectively the same question over and over again. In this case, the issue is temperature records don't cover the whole Earth. Also, why did temperature spike in 1940 before the spike in solar radiation? That suggests something else is going on. Also how about year by year data instead of 11 year averages? And there's an infinite number of explanations for anything.

Comment: @BarryCarter Most people understand that a stratified random sample can accurately measure the population https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/howcan-a-poll-of-only-100/?fbclid=IwAR2SC87Ekyjlh6FsXpNN50dQmEBabIXpK_WDBQ3l2rYd7LZ0-ImsJZJjtIs

Comment: @BarryCarter The yearly data is shown as the very fine lines that jump up and down.

Comment: @DavidHammen I am striving to find the very most effective way to succinctly refute global heating denier liars so that the actual skeptics can be won over to the truth. Currently 33% of Americans do not believe that global heating is even occurring. 67% of Americans with a bachelors degree of better believe that global heating caused by humans is a serious problem.

Comment: The problem is temperature data is not a random sample. If it were a random sample, stratification wouldn't enter into it, it would just be basic statistics (which is what the Scientific American article talks about)

Comment: You're looking for a silver bullet that doesn't exist. Even those who believe global warming is occurring think there's good evidence, but not 100% instant convincing evidence.

Comment: @BarryCarter There is always a best thing we can do. I am looking for the best thing we can do to convince the actual skeptics.

Comment: @BarryCarter A sample of temperatures does not have to be random as long as it is representative.  It is not like the temperatures are going to have subtly  differing opinions.

Comment: You're right, but the sample isn't representative either (or, if it is, how would you prove that? how can you show a non-random sample is as good as a random sample)? We discussed this extensively earlier in chat.

Comment: @BarryCarter We take random sub samples of the random samples and see how much variance that we get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101281/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-polcott).

Comment: @BarryCarter I think that part of the discussion has already been talked through. Hardly anyone believes that the data is unreliable for statistical reasons. They either believe that it is statistically reliable or totally faked.

Comment: Can you source that? And, regardless of whether anyone believes it or not, that is the main problem with the data.